# Make a scrollview's scrollbar not clickable

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a scrollview and its vertical scrollbar. If I touch anything within the scrollview and drag, it will scroll the view the opposite direction I dragged. This is the behaviour I need.

If I on the other hand grab the scrollbar and drag it, it will not be in the opposite direction, but in the same direction as I dragged. I could simply hide the scrollbar, but it gives the user a sense of how much content the scrollview contains.

TL;DR

How do I disable touch events on scrollview's scrollbar?